# Call COM object from classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, com

How to call COM object from classic ASP? I tried hard but cannot find a good tutorial. Any recommendations?

I am using C# in classic ASP.

Comment: you can't be using C# with classic ASP; it doesn't support it!

Comment: I am maintaining some legacy code, and maybe I am wrong to call the name since I think the grammar are similar. :-)

How do you name the programming language, just call it classic ASP?

Comment: IIRC, there were two language engines for classic ASP: VBScript and JavaScript.  You always specified the one to use at the top of your page: <server language="JavaScript"> ... the default was VBSCript but this could be changed for a virtual directory or site through IIS.

Comment: Yes, if I do not assign any script, it should be VBscript? Then I am using VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("Some.Object")
```

For example, see this page:

- http://www.webreference.com/js/column55/activex.html

This assumes that "Some.Object" has been registered as a COM object (for example, using "regsvr32 /register SomeObject.dll").

For further reading, O'Reilly had a decent book on this and you might consider reading this sample chapter:

- http://oreilly.com/catalog/devaspcom2/chapter/ch10.html

or this tutorial:

- http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/980930.htm

Comment: Sorry ars, I am using VBScirpt. I have browsed the tutorials, seems all of them are either dealing with Javascript or dealing with how to create COM object by classic ASP? What I am asking is how to invoke COM object from classic ASP. Any recommended readings?

Comment: Try starting from here on the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524786.aspx  and poke around the rest of the docs.

Answer (score 7):

To instantiate a COM object in classic ASP:

```
Dim rs
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

COM objects are registered (in the registry) with a name known as the ProgId, which is ("ADODB.Recordset") in the above snippet.

Heres's a tutorial: [Using COM Objects](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wsh_lubv.mspx?mfr=true)

Update, in response to posters comments: If you are creating a .NET assembly, then you will need to run [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) on it to create the necessary information to allow COM clients to create .NET Framework classes.

The regasm.exe tool works by reading the declaration of your class, and in particular the class-level attributes GuidAttribute and ProgID as shown here:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[GuidAttribute("581C28BD-E701-4AC1-BD75-0979BCEEC91E"),
ProgId("WordAddin1.Connect")]
public class Connect : Object, Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I am calling some customized 3rd party COM object, not .Net built in ones. Also I am beginner for this topic and I want to read some several-page long tutorials to bring me to the big picture. Any recommended readings?

Comment: Strictly speaking .NET doesn't have any 'builtin' COM objects (but it does provide wrappers over some).

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I am wrting COM object by using C#, and let classic ASP call it. The method about how I create COM object by using C# could be found here => http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_object_in_c_.aspx?display=Print in this method I think there is no progid, just a typelib? I need to generate an additional progid?