# Communication between ASP classic and Windows CE firmware

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, websocket, com, windows-ce

I am developing on a WindowsCE 6.0 platform. So far I had have the Windows CE web server, the ASP interpreter & VBScript built into my CE platform and displaying a few asp web pages.

I would like to exchange data with my c++ application running on the same board. Previously, we used to do that with an ISAPI extension that was opening an internal socket and transferring data both back and forth but this is not practical in a web development point of view. The ISAPI extension has to be included in the CE platform therefore platform being rebuilt means 45 minutes each time you want to modify a coma in the web form.

I know my options are limited. I heard of COM objects. I know nothing about them (how to build, how to include them into the platform nor registering them with a cslid that I don't know how to generate, neither how to 'talk' to them through asp language which is quite limited on windows CE. For example no server method are supported (this includes the `Sever.CreateObject()`) only `Server.MapPath()`. (This is unrelated I know).

I also looked around if this was possible to open a socket directly from VBScript (I do not have .net, only asp classic) and had not found anything quite related to what I want to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would be very limited in Classic ASP,  You are going to have to create that COM component and then maybe call it from JavaScript as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183943/call-com-object-from-classic-asp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a COM interface in your application is the easiest way.
I did not say that it's easy, I said that is the easiest one, keep that in mind!
Using ATL you can wrap most of the boilerplate stuff from COM and have the pages invoking methods inside your application directly.
You should limit the interfaces to IDispach compatible data types (so no structs etc. you'll have to wrap them in a COM object) and debugging will be a sort of a nightmare, having to check issues on the pages and in the C++ code, but it's doable.
And you are not forced to keep the ISAPI dll in the image, you can load it from mass storage and then all you need is to kill and restart the webserver when you need to test a new version. You can also attach the debugger to the HTTP server process (service.exe) and debug it. Putting a DebugBreak call in the first function called usually allows you to load debug symbols and step inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yesturday i was able to 'Recycle' this dll of mine, run it from mass storage as suggested above, and have it 'push' data to my application. I can see the posts separated by the '&' field

What i did is referencing it like this:

that's a start... but both the web site and dll hangs after one usage (probably waiting for something in return that i do not do correctly. I am new to this web world (yeah i know, it's old) and know nothing about it... More of a C++ /embedded guy :)

Answer (score 0):

Html5 also implements a new technology called 'Web sockett' which provides a two-way communication specifically for web based applications. It is discussed:

here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

and here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455